# How can I selectively strip/allow cookies with Varnish?

Tags: http, cookies, varnish

I have Varnish set up to strip all cookies thus:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    #etc
}
```

However, I want to set a cookie called `first_visit` that I don't want Varnish to strip.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look on [Header](https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-header) vmod, it allows manipulations with Set-Cookie

Answer (score 1):

You can also strip cookies in plain VCL:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  # ...
  if ( beresp.http.Set-Cookie 
    && beresp.http.Set-Cookie == "first_visit=Y; path=/; domain=mydomain.tld" 
  ) {
    set beresp.http.first-visit = beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
  }
  # ...
}

sub vcl_deliver {
  # ...
  if (resp.http.first-visit) {
    set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.first-visit;
    unset resp.http.first-visit;
  }
  # ...
}
```

Comment: What if i've got other cookies travelling in that Set-Cookie header?

Comment: This is a conservative approach that I **think** will preserve them, but you can safely drop them forcing to a fixed string in vcl_deliver: `set resp.http.Set-Cookie = "first_visit=Y; path=/; domain=mydomain.tld";`